# How to create global session/application session to store application options using spring?

Tags: java, session, spring-mvc, web

How to create global session/application session to store application options using spring?

I working on web application and i want to retrieve global variables like logo, site name, site url, .... from database just when server run up.

what is the best practice for than and how i can call this variable from jsp ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use application context;

```
public class SomeSpringBean {
  @Autowired
  private WebApplicationContext appContext;

  public void storeAndRetrieveSomethingInAppScope() {
     appContext.getServletContext().setAttribute(String name, Object object);
     Object fromAppContext = appContext.getServletContext().getAttribute(String name);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java code, you can create a session variable :

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("site_name", "Example");
```

Then retrieve it in jsp file with:

```
${sessionScope.site_name}
```